# Why does redefining a global variable inside a function make it undefined

Tags: javascript, scope

So I just stumbled across a bizarre quirk in javascript and I have no idea how this behaviour works.
Take a look at the following code:

```js
var foo = 'bar';
(function() {
  console.log(foo);
}) ();
```

Works as expected, right?
Now run this code:

```js
var foo = 'bar';
(function() {
  console.log(foo);
  var foo = 'bar';
}) ();
```

Why does the redefinition of `foo` **after** the `console.log` call make it undefined?

Comment: Because of declaration hoisting. The declaration makes it a local variable, which is undefined until you execute the initialization statement.

Comment: I think the practical takeaway from this discovery might be, "Never use `var` without a good reason." If you replace `var` with `const` (or `let`), you'll be alerted to a ReferenceError instead of introducing a bug. (And some confusion can also be avoided by never "shadowing" your identifiers in an inner scope, but I understand there may be cases where you want to do this anyway.) Learning how hoisting works is also worthwhile if you'll be doing a good amount of JavaScript programming.